# How to bind data inside a jQuery object to a data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html-table

I am trying to write a program that lists out name of element and its ID after searching the source code. I have used the below script to find the names and display it as alert pop ups. I want it to be displayed inside a data table rather than as popups.

```
<script>
        var $textarea = $('#TextArea1'), $submit = $('#Submit1');
        $submit.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            sourceCode = $textarea.val();
            var $searchObject = $('<div id="Searching"></div>');
            $searchObject.append($(sourceCode));

    alert("Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length);
                $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                    alert("Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name"));
                    alert("ID of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("id"));
                });
</script>
```

Suppose I have a table like this on the client side:

```
<table style="width:100%;" frameborder="0">
          <tr>
              <th>Element </th>
              <th>Element name</th>
              <th>Element ID</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Can anyone help me out with a loop that will add the data in to the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add new rows, you can do the following way. Depending on your need, you can simplify or make it more manageable. For e.g. creating individual `td` elements if you want to add classes etc.

```
var table = $("table-selector");
$searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
                    var newTr = $.parseHTML("<tr><td></td><td>"+$(this).attr("name")+"</td><td>"+$(this).attr("id")+"</td></tr>");
                    $(table).append(newTr);
                    alert("Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name"));
                    alert("ID of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("id"));
                });
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input. I did the same as u mentioned. But it's not adding values to the table. It just showed the result as alert popups.

Comment: Try debugging it in Chrome/Firefox and see if it comes to the line with `...$.parseHTML...`. This code should work, you might have an issue somewhere else.